# Why multiple GET requests to Bootstrap scss files?

Tags: get, bootstrap-5, scss-mixins, morgan

I am currently running a nodejs server using express for my website.

I am running this on my computer, as I test and develop, and it is being displayed on a chrome browser on localhost port 3000.

I have been using Morgan middleware to show GET requests.

Recently something has changed and I am getting output to the console for every GET request that shows the following. There are about 18 similar lines to what is listed below.

```
::1 - - [12/Dec/2023:17:46:41 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 64139 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [12/Dec/2023:17:46:41 +0000] "GET /node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_utilities.scss HTTP/1.1" 200 12970 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [12/Dec/2023:17:46:42 +0000] "GET /node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_utilities.scss HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [12/Dec/2023:17:46:42 +0000] "GET /node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_utilities.scss HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [12/Dec/2023:17:46:42 +0000] "GET /node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_utilities.scss HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [12/Dec/2023:17:46:42 +0000] "GET /node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_utilities.scss HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Why are there so many GET requests to the path :

```
GET /node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_utilities.scss HTTP/1.1
```

I did try to use :

```
morgan(':method')

/* outputs to console when I make any GET request to a page*/

GET
GET
GET
GET
```

I can not understand why so many requests are be made for each GET requests. Could anyone explain to me is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem to be that I was referencing a CDN for some of the styles and also older files in my node-modules.  I have since switched over to using SASS to precompile all of my CSS code into one main file. This has resulted in far less resources being called for.